# How to sum based on different rate for different range of dates?

Tags: mysql

How do I calculate the actual value of a month?

Here is my db structure.

```
date, value
2020-03-01 50
2020-03-02 70
2020-03-03 20
2020-03-04 100
2020-03-05 100
```

But I have different rates for first 3 dates and different rates for last 2 dates.

Query for first 3 dates

```
`SELECT SUM(value) * 5` FROM T1 WHERE date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-03';
```

This will return `700` because `(50+70+20)*5`.

Query for Last 2 dates, only rate is different

```
`SELECT SUM(value) * 3` FROM T1 WHERE date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-03';
```

This will return `600` because `(100+100)*3`.

These are two querys, But I want to achieve that using a single query. I have tried below query but it doesn't work.

```
Select (CASE WHEN date < '2020-03-03' THEN SUM(value) * 5 ELSE SUM(value) * 3 END) as totalValue FROM T1 WHERE date between '2020-03-01' and '2020-03-05';
```

This query returns me only 700, not a total sum of both which should be 700+600 = 1300. It should return me 1300.

Any help? I want to do this only using mysql.

Comment: How do we know which rate apply? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Rate for first 3 is 5, Rate for last 2 is 3 according to above example. Rates are static. Whenever rate is change, it will be from current date.

Comment: Whenever rate is updated, I save rate in my code with with date.

Comment: "save rate in my code" what does that look like?

Comment: I have shorten the above example for SOF, but I have fixed rates for that month, Rate are never gonna change for that month. Actual is For first 25 dates of march 2020, price is 5. but from 26th to 31st march 2020, the price is 3.

Comment: I suggest you revise your question to more accurately reflect your problem

Comment: It is already answered. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your select only return one valuie you can simpy add the results togehter

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            SUM(value) * 5
        FROM
            T1
        WHERE
            `date` BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-03') + (SELECT 
            SUM(value) * 3
        FROM
            T1
        WHERE
            `date` BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-03');
```

[example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6b4f0da3164b00b8aa2f5a397a06bb9)

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna follow this, I will let u know.